# Construct the url to fetch a page by url

Tags: google-sites

With this code I create a page in a Google site:

```
pageEntry = new WebPageEntry();
pageEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(PageTitle));
..
..
client.insert(new URL(getContentFeedUrl()), pageEntry);
```

If the `PageTitle` contains something like "création" the page will created with the name https://sites.google.com/.../.../cration. So "création" is changed to "cration".

Is the process to change the page name available in the API? I would like to fetch the page by its path, but the only key I have is "création".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution would be to strip the diacritics from the characters in the string before setting it as a page title? For instance, [see the javascript function here](http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/). Then you page would be created with the URL `/creation`, which could be more desireable.

Comment: My logic is that it is already happening in the API. If it is not possible to use this process, your option is the second choice. The drawback of your solution is that there will be two processes trying to calculate the same result, probably in  a different way.